# Gaussian method - disadvantages

Tags: matrices

Are there any matrices for which the Gaussian method yields wrong/ or most inaccurate results?
I've implemented a full choice algorythm, where i switch rows and columns so that the current element is biggest.

Comment: If you mean Gaussian Elimination (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination), then it can proven to always reduce a matrix to a reduced row echelon form.

Comment: Gaussian elimination with *complete pivoting* [is quite stable](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=X5YfsuCWpxMC&pg=PA131).

Comment: The main issue with Gaussian Elimination is 'element growth'. In practice, this is not an issue. In fact, just partial pivoting is pretty good, in practice.

Comment: With respect to @copper.hat's comment, you will want to read the book by Golub and Van Loan (which I linked to in my previous comment).

Comment: @J.M.: Useful link. I need to get a newer edition. I just read about rank pivoting in link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for matrices which will give inaccurate results, when solving numerically, you might want to look at the [Hilbert matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix) which has a condition number that grows exponentially with its size.

Comment: right  condition number for matrix should be close to $1$,+1 for Hilbert matrix

Comment: what about the last column? Since the Hilbert Matrix is square, should i fill that with random values?

Comment: The funny thing is that since the Hilbert matrix is symmetric positive definite, you don't even need to pivot! In any event, see [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF03167904) for things on the decomposition of the Hilbert matrix.

Comment: http://kalandarson.blogspot.com/2012/03/naive-gaussian-elimination-for-solving.html

Comment: @coolbartek Sure, just try different values.

Answer (score 1):

as  wikipedia says  it always  works,but  sometimes it needs minor changes, so you can read this document
http://www.personal.psu.edu/bmw5075/360notes.pdf

here  is given advantages and  disadvantages of this method ,their comparison,please see it.

EDITED:

for matrix ,on last page is given  formulas and this statement

Matrix Norms
Matrix norms are natural extensions of vector norms, but are not as clearly defined. They have to be  tested over the whole area of the matrix:

we can's  simply apply on matrix  vector's norm definition,just test on whole matrix

use wikipedia
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm

Comment: looks really nice, but could you explain the condition with the norms a bit more? Should i check for norm 1 or norm infinity?

Comment: please see my edited  version